# Word/ expression/ idiom for "when you realize the good deeds someone has done after their departure/ death"

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

Oftentimes there are people that do good and people don't respect them (and/or rebuke them), but when they leave the place or die, people realize that they were a good person and that what they did was great and good.

**Examples:**

1. There was an employee (A) in a shop who used to keep the shop organized and tidy but the owner of the shop wouldn't respect it and would rebuke him. After A left the job and the owner assigned his job to someone else B, the B wasn't so organized and the shop would always be messed up, the owner realized that the first employee A was much better and what he did was good and he was a nice employee.
2. Sometimes there are wise people that people don't respect much but when they die, people realize how kind and wise they were.

Is there an idiom in English to convey/express that?

**Edit:** I am not sure as to how my question lacks details. I have provided two examples and have explained the situation. Can the close-voters explain how else could I explain and clarify my question?

Comment: There's [***unsung hero***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unsung_hero#:~:text=unsung%20hero%20(plural%20unsung%20heroes,or%20no%20recognition%20for%20them.) *- one who does great deeds but receives little or no recognition for them.* But that doesn't really include the sense of *recognised as great **after** death / departure*.

Comment: There's an idiom '[**ahead of one's time**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ahead%20of%20one%27s%2Fits%20time)', but I'm not sure that works here. /// Another saying/quote is '[**genius is never understood in its own time**](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/bill_watterson_378098)'.

Comment: Didn’t know know how good you had it.  You took them for granted.

Comment: I suggest there is no such phrase.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Not possible. People will always suggest the "closest" phrase, which is never very close, but the one with the highest votes will be considered the actual answer.

Comment: @OwenReynolds Well, shame on them. By the way, what's that "Not possible"?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of [On the darkest nights, the moon is dearly missed](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/348613/in-the-darkest-nights-the-moon-is-dearly-missed/348655#348655) ('the translation of an Arabic proverb which means that during ... hard times you miss someone who made life easier, happier ...').

Comment: Regarding close votes - I don’t think I voted on this question, but I noticed that you haven’t provided textual context for the word/phrase/idiom you’re looking for. Textual context makes a difference to what people might suggest. E.g. “He was a ___(adjective) man.” vs “I wish I had known this ___(noun) better.” vs “He did so much for the community. ___(idiom).”

Answer (score 9):

How about **you don't know what you've got till it's gone**?

> You don't fully appreciate people or things until you lose them.
>
> > My grandfather passed away last month, and I miss him so much. Truly, you never know what you've got till it's gone.
>
> [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/you+never+know+what+you%27ve+got+till+it%27s+gone)

See also the song [Big Yellow Taxi](https://jonimitchell.com/music/song.cfm?id=13) (1970), which seems to be the origin of this expression (if not, it's what popularized it).

Comment: "not fully appreciate" seems to make this not match. You appreciated them while alive, but just not enough. The Q seems to be about when a reputation flips from bad to good after death.

Answer (score 3):

If context includes death, **posthumous recognition** can be a good fit.

**"posthumous"**

> - "occurring or continuing after one's death"[**¹**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/posthumous)

> - "following or occurring after death"[**²**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/posthumous)

If the dead one reaches world-wide recognition and admiration, such as Van Gogh, Emily Dickinson or Allan Poe, you can use **"posthumous fame"**

If the recipient has only quit, you may well use one of several sayings such as **"you only realize the importance of someone when they are gone"** or **"you never know the value of a person until they're gone"**

Answer (score 2):

**distance lends enchantment (to the view)**
*proverb*

> When one is removed from something, it becomes deceptively appealing.

*But you hated that rickety old house when we lived there! Remember that distance lends enchantment to the view.*

[The Free Dictionary]